# Convert Django Views to rest services

Tags: python, django

I have an application created long back, now client want to expose its some of views as APIs without breaking existing functionality, so that they can directly consume APIs using REST Tools to see the reports.

Is there any easier way, I can convert my function to a REST View.

**P.S** - I kept code shorter here to keep question simple, but in fact, its much complex in the actual app.

eg. 
    URL : -

```
    `path('/users', views.show_user_details, name='users'),`
```

VIEW

```
 def show_user_details(request, user_id):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, "Users.html", {"users":users})
```

In REST Views, I want it to convert its input and output so that it can be accessible with same urls(or with little modifications), without much updating the existing views.

```
  `path('rest/users', views.show_user_details, name='users'),`   #-- I am ok to add new url like this, but without much change in  existing view .

def show_user_details(request, user_id):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return JsonResponse({"users":users})
```

Comment: `django-rest-framework` is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that a normal website visit is still a `GET` request and `GET` is just one of your usual REST actions, you'll probably want to prepare your own independent API endpoint. Check out [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for that, and you might just feel at home for this task.